# The security problem of tx.origin in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design, security

The book Mastering Ethereum pointed out that it is not safe to use tx.origin in smart contracts. I want to know what is the reason for insecurity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Primarily to protect against phishing contracts**.

`tx.origin` is the original user that initiated the transaction.

So if contract has some method like this (in Vyper):

```
def burnBalance():
    assert tx.origin == owner, "You are not the owner"
    balance[tx.origin] = 0
```

Then another smart contract can "phish" you with a proxy function - If you accidentally interact with this evil contract then you will lose your funds:

```
# The attacking contract calling the original contract
OriginalContract(originalContractAddress).burnBalance()
```

If `burnBalance` was instead using msg.sender then this attack will fail:

```
# This is the correct way of checking permissions
def burnBalance():
    assert msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner"
    balance[msg.sender] = 0
```

`msg.sender` is the intermediate caller; In this case the phishing contract is the `msg.sender`.

---

*Sidenote: There is actually some discussion in  the ethereum community on removing tx.origin all together. Personally I disagree with this as it has some niche use cases. One of which is checking if the caller who is interacting with the smart contract is another smart contract or a normal user. e.g.*

```
assert tx.origin == msg.sender, "Only users can interact with this contract"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has benefited me a lot